# Grails URLMapping to Response Codes doesn't work if the request is POST

Tags: grails, url-mapping, http-response-codes

I am a little crazy about this.
At first, my mapping is like below

```
"500"(view:'/error/exception')
```

But, then we found, if the exception is throw in Spring Security code, the error page is not correct. By looking the source code, I change the mapping from view to action

```
"500"(controller: "error", action: "exception")
```

and, in the action I will send a **redirect** request to another action which will render view. Seems everything work.

However, today I found if the request which cause exception is GET, it works, if it is a POST, then nothing rendered, it just return 404 to browser.

Could anybody tell me how to walkaround it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a walkaround. 
Config mapping as:

```
"500"(view:'/error/exception')
```

In the view,  write an redirect

```
<% response.sendRedirect("/xxx/error/exception") %>
```

Then , render view in the ErrorControl, exception action.

Waiting for better solution.